# Monitor Windows Pod In K8s

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a cluster with multiple nodes. the majority of them is linux nodes but i have one windows node.
When I tried multiple guides, I did not managed see the metrics of the pods that run on the windows node.
Tried the built in of k8s, the built-in metrics of lens and the kube-prometheus-stack. (Great guide here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW-E8THfvPY)

None of them worked on the windows pods.

I now wonder, Is that even possible to monitor a windows os based pod?

Comment: Normally the pod metrics are exposed through the kubelet service, did you try it?

Comment: @YwH Tried that. Does not work on windows pods for monitoring over time.